# What version of salesforce for outlook are my users on?

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook, version-control

We have people that have had some issues with Salesforce for outlook--and usually it's because they're using an outdated version of it.  Newer versions tend to alert the user that an update is available, but it hasn't always been that way.

I have a place in setup where I can see which users are using SFFO and when they logged in, etc.  Is there a way to a view a list of which version they're using so I can see who needs to update?

Comment: Can you identify the Outlook addin in the `Setup > Administration Setup > Manage Users > Login History`? The values in the Login Type, Browser, Application, Client Version and API Version might be sufficient to determine the plugin version.